2001 Mercedes W203 C200 Kompressor Charging at 11.7-12V
I have a 2001 W203 C200 Kompressor with the M111 E20ML engine. I am getting the ff. scenarios on battery voltage/charging:

On cold start, voltage is good at 14.0V. Even if I restart the engine, it's still at 14.0-14.2V.

After a few mins when the engine is at around 80C or higher, I would restart the engine and the voltage would be only around 11.9-12V, the battery/alternator visit workshop would appear. And then, after a minute or so, it would go back up to 13.8-14.0V but still the warning light would show.


Could this be an alternator issue, or could it be that the battery needs replacement? It starts every time though. The batter had around 60% life when it was tested last year in October 2023.

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

This seems more than likely a battery issue and not an alternator issue. Your first bet would to get the battery tested again. You don't state how old the battery is, but expected life out of one is usually five years for a decent battery. If anywhere near that (or even past the five year mark), it may just be time to replace it anyways as a maintenance item. The battery is also the easiest thing to check and replace (if needed). Also, your description of it seems to be telling me there may be a failing cell in the battery. Dendrites may be causing issues in a single cell which could possibly do something like this.
